# how to install windows 7 on a blank pc with no mouse or keybord

Tags: desktop

Hi im trying to install windows 7 on  a blank pc with no mouse or keyboard working is there a way can I install windows without any usb working as mouse and keyboard both usb

Comment: You don't seem to have made any effort to research this... There are multiple results on Google which answer your question.

Comment: Not to mention that booting off the Windows installation media with a USB mouse and keyboard plugged into the computer usually works just fine...

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of modern computers support USB input devices at a BIOS/UEFI level- you do not need to do anything whatsoever- its the default setting on most computers.

Comment: It is the default setting (and support) indeed but the majority of motherboards allow disabling (legacy) USB support which, once done, disables all USB input devices until some OS (or OS installer) takes over. The result is the impossibility of accessing BIOS/UEFI to change boot order and other settings. I think this is the point of the question.

Comment: Hi usb not working and disk stops at choose language here is where i am stuck is there any way to pre select this so the disk just runs